# Move right column to the top

Tags: html, css

I'm using @media query and I'm trying to make right column to move to the top of .left div when shrinking the screen. So far I can only get it to move to the top of .middle div. I tried to play with positioning but it seems it doesn't work the way I need.

I need this structure when shrinking:

**Left Column | Right Column 

Middle column**

Right now:

**Left Column 

Middle column | Right Column**

See the code below.
Thank You.

```css
div {
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header {
    height: 52px;
    width: calc(100% - 16px);
    background-color: #B2D490;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
}
h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;
    color: #00457D;
}
.left {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #C7E6FF;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 64px;
    margin-right: calc(50% - 450px);
}
.middle {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #DEF0FF;
    margin-top: 64px;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #C7E6FF;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 64px;
}
#footer {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #57C449;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
p {
    color: #00579E;
}
#footer p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 35px;
}
span {
    color: #D4EBFF;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  body {
      width: 95%;
  }
   .left {
      width: 60%;
      margin-right: 0;
     
   }
   .middle {
      width: 60%;
      margin-top: 10px;
   
   }
   .right {
      width: calc(40% - 10px);
      margin-top: 10px;


      
   }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  <title>My Resume</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="header">
     <h1>My <span>Resume</span></h1>
 </div>
 <div class="left">
     <h2>Left Column</h2>
         <ul>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
         </ul>
 </div>
  <div class="middle">
     <h2>Centered Center Column</h2>
         <ul>
                <li><p>Some Text</p></li>
                <li><p>Some Text</p></li>
                <li><p>Some Text</p></li>
        </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
     <h4>Right Column</h4>
         <ul>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
        </ul>
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both; border:none; border-radius: none;"></div>
 <div id="footer">
     <p>© 2015 Me - the Programmer</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.right {
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute; //added this
    background-color: #C7E6FF;
    right: 0; //added this
    margin-top: 64px;
}
```

In media query use this class

```
 .right {
      width: calc(40% - 10px);
      margin-top: 64px;  //changed this 
   }
```

**[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/vw4b99b1/)**

Comment: Thank You, that's a good answer, but notice the right column right margin. I'll try to fix it in a moment.

Comment: Well, adding margin-right: 8px; seems to work. But now margin to the left doesn't work properly and changes every time the screen shrinks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Adding right: 8px; do the trick too. But then again there's right margin problem.

Comment: right margin should be the fixed width but it changes every time the screen shrinks.